# Is there a flutter library for access to secure enclave?

Tags: flutter, keychain, android-keystore, dart-pub

I've recently started using Flutter for mobile app development, which, in my case, usually involves cryptography.  I'd like to be able to generate/use keys in the secure enclave on [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave) and the keystore on [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore), per the documentation provided in the links above.

I've found a library for [secure storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) and, of course there is [PointyCastle](https://github.com/PointyCastle/pointycastle), but none of these options allow private keys to be generated and stored specifically in the enclave, without insecure handling in application code.

Is this available yet?

Comment: Isn't `secure enclave` exclusive to ios?

Comment: edited to clarify

Answer (score 1):

There are no packages for this, but You could easily develop Your own Flutter plugin.
Check the [docs for Flutter plugin development (link)](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin). Flutter plugin is nothing but a fancy name for a Dart package that does some stuff on iOS and Android (natively).

In essence, it boils down to writing quite simple wrapper classes and then calling native methods from there. If You ever had any experience with native development, it will be a piece of cake for you. :)

You can use the source code of [FlutterSecureStorage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) plugin as a reference. It has some smaller issues, but it's a great starting point.

I hope You will make it and then write back with a github or pub.dev link! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://pub.dev/packages/key_enclave is a libary to use the secure enclave.

However, the lib is a bit limited and does not have a lot of recent development.